# Installing and using MS SQL JDBC Driver?

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, database-connection, environment-variables

I am trying to install JDBC Drivers for MS SQL Server instance running on my local workstation. This http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313100  link starts a tutorial on getting started with JDBC. However it asks me to configure the following four env variables:-

1. \Your installation path\Lib\Msbase.jar
2. \Your installation path\Lib\Msutil.jar
3. \Your installation path\Lib\Mssqlserver.jar

None of the above three files comes with standard JDBC driver download from Microsoft site. I tried downloading these jars manually from different locations, however they all have been removed. It just looks like these are very old and no longer used.

I was wondering if I still need these jars and env variables pointed to them for me to use the JDBC drivers for connecting to local MS SQL Server instance?

If answer to this question where can I find them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0. Download here [Microsoft JDBC Driver 4.0 for SQL Server](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11774)

add sqljdbc4.jar to classpath in your project settings

Comment: What I meant was the package I download from that location contains only sqljdbc.jar. It does NOT contain the aforementioned Msbase.jar, Msutil.jar and mssqlserver.jar

Comment: I never used Msbase.jar, Msutil.jar and mssqlserver.jar 
I have always used in my projects sqljdbc4.jar

Comment: mssqlserver.jar, msbase.jar, msutil.jar is for SqlServer 2000 

sqljdbc4.jar 2005 and higher

Comment: Gotcha. The tutorial is bit out-dated then. It refers to those three jars when we only need sqljdbc4.jar....

Comment: First line says:
"This article describes how to connect to SQL Server 2000 by using the Microsoft SQL Server 2000 driver for JDBC."