# Installing MS SQL driver into Eclipse Maven

Tags: java, sql-server, eclipse, maven, jdbc

How do I install MSSQL driver in my project with Eclipse's maven? (m2e)? And also make it not conflict with Vaadin? When I install the MSSQL driver locally [following these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32760177/4691343), during the compile and runtime, it says "Could not find archetype from Vaadin-addons."

I have the code:

```
                Connection con = null;
                Statement stmt = null;
                ResultSet rs = null;
                try {
                     Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");  
                    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://server;databaseName=dbname;user=username;password=password");
                    String sql = "Select * from Table1";
                    stmt = con.createStatement( );
                    rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

                    while (rs.next()){
                        contractorsList.addBean(new Contractor(rs.getString(1), 
                                rs.getString(2), 
                                rs.getString(3), 
                                rs.getString(4), 
                                rs.getString(5), 
                                rs.getString(6))); 
                    }

                } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally{
                    try { con.close();  } catch (SQLException e) {}
                    try { rs.close();   } catch (SQLException e) {}
                    try { stmt.close(); } catch (SQLException e) {}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:450)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:403)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
```

Which means that it can't find my driver, I think. So I'm following [this tutorial](http://techmajik.com/2014/04/24/how-to-setup-maven-dependency-for-microsoft-sql-server/) on installing the MS SQL driver. [I download the driver from microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11774) and then I unzip it here:

```
C:\SQLDriver
```

In Eclipse, on my project folder, I right click > Debug As > Debug Configurations >

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:\SQLDriver\sqljdbc_4.0\enu\sqljdbc4.jar -DgroupId=com.microsoft.sqlserver -DartifactId=sqljdbc4 -Dversion=4.0.2206.100 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Then I add in the following in my POM

```
<properties>
<!–….other versions–>
<sqlserver.version>4.0.2206.100</sqlserver.version>
</properties>
...
<dependency>
<groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
<artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
<version>${sqlserver.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I get an error that it can't find my dependency, So I look up the question here, and I found out that I simply need to add sqljdbc4 to my classpath.

I have no idea what that means but [google took me here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/brian_swan/2011/03/02/getting-started-with-the-sql-server-jdbc-driver/) So I attempt to follow the instructions.

In System Properties > Advanced > Environment Variable under Variables, I add the following:

[image]

I searched here and it looks like someone else asked the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18200823/installing-and-using-ms-sql-jdbc-driver)

I honestly don't know what people mean by add it to the classpath. Do they mean paste the jars in the same folder as the project? Either way, I just found a .classpath file in my project and added these:

[image]

How do I get maven to use this microsoft sql driver?

**[Edit]** When going to Libraries > Maven Dependencies, right click > build path > configure build path, I see this:

[image]

Which, when I click, it doesn't let me edit the path of that file. I'm not sure where to edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to download the source code and the java docs for all the maven dependencies. You can do that by right clicking the maven as discussed here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22352526/1475228

Then only you can run the code.

Also look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30111956/1475228). This is the one that helped mine.

Comment: I tried to do as you said, Right Click > Maven > Update project. Then when I run the project, I still get class not found error.

Comment: @arsarc Did you add the jar to your build path?

Comment: Yes, Libraries > Maven Dependencies > Build Path > Configure Build Path > Add External Jars and added sqljdbc4.jar and sqljdbc.jar. There is an error though, I'll update the question with it.

Comment: @arsarc Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19537396/missing-artifact-com-microsoft-sqlserversqljdbc4jar4-0/30111956#30111956

Comment: @arsarc worked for me

Comment: I used the jtds that it recommended. Thank you.